# Firebase : Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module Require stack: Adding key.json which in function directory to admin.js file getting this error

Tags: node.js

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
   const serviceAccount=require("./social.json");  
   admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
       databaseURL: "https://socialapefirebaseio.com"});
   const db = admin.firestore();
  module.exports = { admin, db };
```

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module Require stack:I am getting error key file not found.

Comment: My keyfile is stored inside Firebase function directory not able to get what is problem here.

Comment: Please add the full stack error as you see it in the terminal.  Also add as many details as you can to make it easier for others to help you. Also don't add comments to add details, edit your question instead.

Comment: While adding firebase key.json  in function directory both index.js and .key.json file are in same folder but still i am getting error in terminal not found required module,when i deploy it using firebase deploy command.